# Are you able to declare a variable as another variable's content in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, class, variables

So basically,

I have made a class called `Application`.

The way it works is:

(1) Someone makes an application

(2) They answer some questions

(3) A new Application object is created

This issue with this is that there could be multiple applications on at the same time, but the object's name would be the same. In addition, the applicant's name would be stored in a variable called `name`. Is there a way to make every new Application object the `name` variable's content?

***FYI, this will be done using a Discord bot, but that won't change anything***

EDIT: My code (upon request):

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client();

class Application {
    constructor(name, position) {
        this.Name = name
        this.Position = position
        this.Open = true
    }
    close() {
        this.Open = false
    }
    open() {
        this.Open = true
    }
    
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('ready')
});
client.on('message', message => {
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if (!client.commands.has(commandName)) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(commandName);
    if (message.content === 'newapp') {
        const newapp = new Application(args[0], args[1])
    }
});

client.login('token has gone')
```

Comment: Will you provide a code example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Ok, I will edit the post now.

Comment: The link you provided takes me to a long in page. Will you please post your code directly in the question instead of linking to it?

Comment: If you're weird about private tokens, simply omit them from your code before posting it.

Comment: "*variables are not yet added*" - can you please add those variables? It's really hard to understand what you are asking without them.

Comment: What do you mean by "*but the object's name would be the same*"? Yes, every new `newapp` message creates a separate `const newapp` variable, but I don't see how that is a problem.

Comment: @Bergi because newapp is one variable name, you can't name more variables newapp. Can't you?

Comment: @LyamDexterMosnier There *are* multiple variables. Every time the message handler function gets called, it creates a new variable. Of course, in any scope, you'll just see one of them. Still not sure what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but all of them will need to be seen, so the name of the object would have to be the applicants name, and I don't know how to do that. @Bergi

Comment: What do you mean by "*the name of the object*"? If you mean the `.Name` property of the instance, that should receive the first argument value of the command (from the message content) just fine.

Comment: Not the property, but the name in the declaration: ``let name = new Application``

Answer (score -1):

Not sure you can stream a variables value to another, but you can kind of do it by:

- Creating another thread to consistently update the value of said variable

I'd say you could basically do it in python by doing this:

```py
import threading

variable = ""

class Application:
    """Add your application stuff here"""
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

def stream(application):
    global variable

    while True:
        variable = application.name

def other_function():
    """Add your main code here"""
    pass

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=stream)
thread1.run()
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=other_function)
thread2.run()
```

It basically runs two functions at the same time for you.

Comment: This would be absolutely horrible for power/battery and resource usage.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was using python(discord.py). Also @JustinTaddei I know it may be but I don't think you can do asyncio in this case. Feel free to correct me!

Comment: @codernaut1 I'm still not even sure what they're trying to accomplish :)

Comment: They are running the code at the same time, so stream() is updating the variable `name`, while the other thread is doing whatever else the owner wants.

Comment: Should I move my bot to Python then

Comment: Its your choice. Python has alot of features but may be slower than JS.